# Internet speed is 512 kbps but it gives only 60kbps speed

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, speed

My internet speed is about 50-60 kbps but on company plan and there website it shows that Internet speed provided is 512 kbps can anyone explain this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why always Internet speed is divided?](http://superuser.com/questions/789780/why-always-internet-speed-is-divided)

Comment: 512 Kbps ~= 60 KB/s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be getting 50-60 Kilobytes/second not Kilobits/second.1 byte = 8 bits.So please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

The plan is 512 kbps, which means 512 kbps (kilobits/second), ie) 512000/8=64000 bytes/second.
So, it means the downloading speed is 64 kBps(kilobytes/second). So, 60kBps which you are getting is 100% correct speed. Do not worry.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 512 Kbps connection not a 512 KBps connection. That 'B' makes a huge difference. 512 Kbps is 512 KiloBitsPerSecond and 512 KBps is 512 KiloBytesPerSecond. 1byte=8bits and download speed is measured in bytes not bits. So, divide 512 by 8=64 KiloBytesPerSecond. That mean you are getting the maximum speed from your internet connection.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.